# magento2. Errors during migration

Tags: magento2, migration

During the migration I encountered this problem.

[image]

What to do to correct these errors?

Comment: try to fresh database

Answer (score 0):

You have to need refer below links for fix the Integrity check failed error. Hope it help.

https://oyenetwork.com/articles/data-migration-to-magento2-case-study/

https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/174

https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/15